# Load views from location outside the mvc website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I'm trying to load an MVC view form a folder outside the location of the app.

My app is in `C:\dev\myproject\` and the view file i'm trying to load is located in `D:\viewsfolder\something` is it possible to do that?

I tried passing an absolute path to the `return View()` method but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported by standard ASP.NET MVC. You may take a look at the [`RazorEngine plugin`](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine) which allows you to render a Razor view from a string.

You haven't really explained why you need to do that by the way. Maybe there's a better approach to your particular problem.

Comment: I need this because i need my views in a common location between different web servers. and +1 for RazorEngine, I forgot about it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to have your Views Precompiled into a dll which can be used across multiple locations with only one code base.

This can be done using the Razor Generator Plugin which you can find here:

http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/